# Monero RPC send transaction from address

Tags: monerod, address, monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-hash

I used the following command to pass a monero transaction with the daemon :

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"transfer","params":{"account_index":2,"destinations":[{"amount":100000000,"address":"9wNgSYy2F9qPZu7KBjvsFgZLTKE2TZgEpNFbGka9gA5zPmAXS35QzzYaLKJRkYTnzgArGNX7TvSqZC87tBLwtaC5RQgJ8rm"}]}}

But I need a command whose I can define the source address from which I can send the coin monero.

Answer (score 1):

Each account in a wallet has a number, and each subaddress in an account has a number.

You can add the `account_index` and `subaddr_indices` options when calling the `transfer` method to indicate from which subaddress (or subaddresses) the coins will be taken.

For example to use subaddress n°3 in account n°2 as source of the coins:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0",
 "id":"0",
 "method":"transfer",
 "params":{"account_index":2,
           "subaddr_indices":[3],
           "destinations":[{"amount":100000000, "address":"9wNgSYy2F9qPZu7KBjvsFgZLTKE2TZgEpNFbGka9gA5zPmAXS35QzzYaLKJRkYTnzgArGNX7TvSqZC87tBLwtaC5RQgJ8rm"}],
           "get_tx_key":true}}
```

The documentation of the `transfer` method is [here](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer).

Comment: I already tried with these  params but the transaction did not send and this error message is returned :                                                   
  { "error": {
    "code": -16,
    "message": "tx not possible"
  },
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}

Comment: Have you checked if the source subaddress contains enough funds for the amount sent and the fee? Are there more details about the error in the logs of monero-wallet-rpc?

Comment: yes the address contains enough mony for the transaction and all the params is correct but the same errors